# Apache on windows server can't write to file

Tags: php, apache, apache2

We have installed Apache 2.2 on a windows server 2003.

We want to make apache able to write to files on the disk but we don't know as what user Apache works as.

How do we allow Apache to write to files on a Windows server 2003?

UPDATE:
The user is running as 'SYSTEM' and we have tried giving that user full permission to all folders and files. Also we have given 'Everyone' full permission to all folders and files.  We have restarted Apache, cleared all cookies, restarted IE and still we get a message, from phpMyAdmin, that we don't have write permission.

Comment: very much programming related :)

Comment: How is setting up user permissions or a server configuration file in any way programming related?

Comment: @DanielSloof Server configuration files are technically code (according to the definition by [Law Insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/computer-code)), and web servers host files that we have most likely coded. Got it? 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in

Start --> Administrative Tools --> Services

in that list you should see the Apache Service (assuming you installed it as a service)

Right click properties, Log On tab should tell you who it's logged on as.

Comment: Why is this upvoted so high? How is this answering the question? I could only write to my httpd.conf file by giving Users write permission _even though_ the Log On tab said Apache was running under SYSTEM, which already had full control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the "Everyone"-group access to the files? Do not forget to reset this setting in production.

To see which user apache runs under, use the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permission problem for the user Apache is running under.

If you check the running processes, you should see Apache and the user it is running under. You should be able to give that user write permission.