# creating thumbnail images with php - writing permissions

Tags: php, image, gd

EDIT: Problem solved:
Stupid little twit that I am, I had neglected to give the file a name. $testSiteDir was a path with no filename. How can a file be saved without a name! D'Oh!
sorry ;)

---

I know there's lots of similar questions around and I've been reading through them but since I've sort of had to build a hybrid of all the tutorials and articles I've got some code which I hoped would work but doesn't.

I did at one point manage to create copies of the images into the folder I wanted using the copy() function to move it, which worked. But since I want to resize it I need to use GD (as far as I can tell)

here's my code:

```
if (is_dir($BooksDir)) {
if ($dh = opendir($BooksDir)) {
    while (($folder = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        $count++;
        $exclude = array('.','..','etc.');
        if (!in_array($folder, $exclude)){
            echo '<div ' . ($count&1 ? 'class="oddrow"' : 'class="evenrow"') . '>';
            echo $folder . "<br/>" . $count;
            $subDir = $BooksDir . '/' . $folder;
            $filesnfolders = scandir($subDir);
            foreach ($filesnfolders as $file) {
                $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'png' || $ext == 'gif') {
                    if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') {
                        $origimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($subDir. '/' . $file);
                        $thHeight = 100;
                        $thWidth = 100;
                        $mainWidth = imagesx( $origimg );
                        $mainHeight = imagesy( $origimg );
                        $myThumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($thWidth, $thHeight);
                        imagecopyresampled( $myThumbnail, $origimg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $mainWidth, $mainHeight );
                        imagejpeg( $myThumbnail, $testSiteDir );
                    }
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
```

}

When I try using the above I get the error that I don't have permission to write to that folder: Unable to open 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test' for writing: Permission denied in...

I've got three text books and read a bunch of articles about images and php, I haven't seen anywhere where it tells me what to do

what's going wrong :)

Comment: Is `C:/xampp/htdocs/test` read-only?

Comment: I've tried changing it with rightclick->properties->unselect readonly but that didn't make ay difference, I also tried changing the owner of the folder but that didn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting write permissions on Windows can be less than obvious.

Try these instructions http://drupal.org/node/202491 and see how you get on.

If you use Xampp as a PHP installation, it usually seems to propagate write permissions through the whole directory structure of htdocs. Very handy. Not sure why it hasn't done it for you.

EDIT: just noticed that the Drupal page relates to IIS. Maybe this will be better...
[Apache on windows server can't write to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688962/apache-on-windows-server-cant-write-to-file)

Comment: Hey there, read those articles but I'm none the wiser, Thanks for pointing out it's probably to do with windows, I'm on windows 7 - just need to figure out whats going wrong! Why's everything so hard!

Comment: @crazysarah It's not so hard, Crazy. You could prove to yourself that it's possible by choosing "Everyone" and allowing that user to write to the directory. It's not good practice though.